# How to remove all roles from the user in spatie/laravel-permission

Tags: laravel, laravel-permission

whats the best or the usual way to remove all roles from a user?

I tried

`$roles = $user->getRoleNames(); $user->removeRole($roles);`

```
Return value of App\User::getStoredRole() must implement interface Spatie\Permission\Contracts\Role, instance of Illuminate\Support\Collection returned
```

Answer (score 11):

Use the plain Laravel `detach` method like so:

`$user->roles()->detach();`

Answer (score 3):

You can also remove all roles by syncing to an empty array, like so.

```
$user->syncRoles([]);
```

I confirmed it works on version 5.8.

Answer (score 1):

From reading the documentation it clearly says that you can pass a `Collection` instance to the `removeRole` so I think you are doing it right.

> The assignRole, hasRole, hasAnyRole, hasAllRoles and removeRole functions can accept a string, a \Spatie\Permission\Models\Role object or an \Illuminate\Support\Collection object.

Comment: I tried this 

`$roles = $user->getRoleNames();
            $user->removeRole($roles);`

`Return value of App\User::getStoredRole() must implement interface Spatie\Permission\Contracts\Role, instance of Illuminate\Support\Collection returned"`

Comment: I think you will have to iterate over the collection then, I would also bring this up on their issues github page

Answer (score 1):

I dod it now in this way `$user->removeRole($user->roles->first());`

Answer (score 0):

This works fine even on Laravel 7

For Roles:
`$user->syncRoles([]);`

For Permissions:
`$user->syncPermissions([]);`

Answer (score 0):

From Spatie documentation you can find ther is a way to remove all previous roles and assign new roles with simple

```
$user->syncRoles($roles);
```

For reference you can visit this [link](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v3/basic-usage/basic-usage)